# AngularJS filter for multiple strings

Tags: angularjs

I'm working through the AngularJS tutorial, and understand the basics of

However, the out of the box implementation seems limited to just filter the list of items to the exact word or phrase entered in .

Example: if the query is "table cloth", the result list can include a result with this phrase, "Decorative table cloth", but won't include "Decorative cloth for table" because the filter is just a continuous search string.

I know there's the ability to add custom filters, but at first glance it seems like those are mainly transforms.

Is there any way to add a custom filter so that both "Decorative cloth for table" and "Decorative table cloth" show up in the filtered result set?

Comment: would have to create custom filter that looks for individual words, not full string. Might also consider using a [fuzzy search library](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+fuzzy+search&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) also.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994699/angularjs-filtering-multiple-expressions

Comment: with custom filter you can echieve everything you want, any regex and statements

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Please see [surfbuds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459798/angularjs-filter-for-multiple-strings/23452217#23452217) answer below as it is superior**

Just roll with your own filter:

```
.filter("myFilter", function(){
    return function(input, searchText){
        var returnArray = [];
        var searchTextSplit = searchText.toLowerCase().split(' ');
        for(var x = 0; x < input.length; x++){
            var count = 0;
            for(var y = 0; y < searchTextSplit.length; y++){
                if(input[x].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTextSplit[y]) !== -1){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(count == searchTextSplit.length){
                 returnArray.push(input[x]);   
            }
        }
        return returnArray;
    }
});
```

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/Cq3PF/

This filter makes sure that all search words are found.

Comment: Thanks very much to the commenters and the answerer...awesome stuff, guys!

Answer (score 19):

**Some improvements to the above custom filter**:

Instead of using a loop within a loop, counts, and indexOf,  this one uses **regular expressions** to achieve a logical **AND** and also a logical **OR** depending on the third argument to the filter *(input array of strings, search terms, AND or OR)*.

Have a look at the forked Fiddle with the two types of filter and results:

http://jsfiddle.net/jonjon/Cx3Pk/23/

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .filter("myFilter", function () {
    return function (input, searchText, AND_OR) {
        var returnArray = [],
            // Split on single or multi space
            splitext = searchText.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/),
            // Build Regexp with Logical AND using "look ahead assertions"
            regexp_and = "(?=.*" + splitext.join(")(?=.*") + ")",
            // Build Regexp with logicial OR
            regexp_or = searchText.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, "|"),
            // Compile the regular expression
            re = new RegExp((AND_OR == "AND") ? regexp_and : regexp_or, "i");

        for (var x = 0; x < input.length; x++) {
            if (re.test(input[x])) returnArray.push(input[x]);
        }
        return returnArray;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the superior answer, it is faster.

Comment: @MathewBerg Thanks for noticing. Regular expressions are often overlooked by JS programmers but they definitely are as useful today as they were when Perl was the main scripting language of the web.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this, but running into problems (no results).  Could it be that my input is a large array of objects?

Comment: @bluemihai The "input" argument is an array of strings in this example, so you have to provide the expected argument type for this function to work. This could be done by filtering your input and extracting the strings or group of strings on which you want to perform a boolean search.

Comment: The only one that actually worked for me. Thank You.

Comment: Excellent solution except it implements a regex search instead of a simple string search, and causes errors if the search string is not a valid regex. The argument should be escaped first, e.g.: `searchText = ('' + searchText).replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, '\\$1');`

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you could use the default Angular filter within your custom filter like so:

```
angular.module('app').filter("multiWordFilter", function($filter){
    return function(inputArray, searchText){
        var wordArray = searchText ? searchText.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/) : [];
        var wordCount = wordArray.length;
        for(var i=0;i<wordCount;i++){
            inputArray = $filter('filter')(inputArray, wordArray[i]);
        }
        return inputArray;
    }
});
```

This could be embellished further with user2005009's AND_OR comparator.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version. It uses JonoWilko's method of using the built in `filterFilter` combined with surfbud's AND/OR flag (defaulted to `"AND"`).

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('filters').filter('searchFilter', function($filter) {

    return function(inputArray, searchText, booleanOp) {
        booleanOp = booleanOp || 'AND';

        var searchTerms = (searchText || '').toLowerCase().split(/\s+/);

        if (booleanOp === 'AND') {
            var result = inputArray;
            searchTerms.forEach(function(searchTerm) {
                result = $filter('filter')(result, searchTerm);
            });

        } else {
            var result = [];
            searchTerms.forEach(function(searchTerm) {
                result = result.concat($filter('filter')(inputArray, searchTerm));
            });
        }

        return result;
    };
});
```

**CoffeeScript**

```
angular.module('filters').filter 'searchFilter', ($filter)->

    (inputArray, searchText='', booleanOp = 'AND')->
        searchTerms = searchText.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/)

        if booleanOp is 'AND'
            result = inputArray
            searchTerms.forEach (word)->
                result = $filter('filter')(result, word)

        else
            result = []
            searchTerms.forEach (word)->
                result = result.concat $filter('filter')(inputArray, word)

        result
```

**'AND' Usage (default)**

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | searchFilter: searchInputText"></div>
```

**'OR' Usage**

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | searchFilter: searchInputText : 'OR'"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a multiple word search on a object as follows:

```
.filter("myFilter", function(){
    return function(input, searchText){
         var returnArray = [];
         var searchTextSplit = searchText.toLowerCase().split(' ');
        for(var x = 0; x < input.length; x++){
             var count = 0;
            for(var y = 0; y < searchTextSplit.length; y++){
                angular.forEach(input[x], function(item){
                    if(item.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTextSplit[y]) !== -1){
                        count++;
                    }
                });

            }
            if(count == searchTextSplit.length){
                 returnArray.push(input[x]);   
            }
        }
        return returnArray;
    }
});
```

[Working demo in js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adefokun/ww9j7qc3/1/)

Comment: In the future, please [edit] in the relevant code as text in your post.  External links are no substitute for code in the post itself.

Comment: How would you implement this type of search? In this example in their table you can type part of a word, hit the space key, and type part of another word in a column, and it still filters accordingly.
https://datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

Not a one liner but still quite short and fun

```
app.filter("filterall",function($filter) {
    return function(arr,t){
        (t?t.split(/\s+/):[]).forEach(function(v){ arr = $filter('filter')(arr,v); });
        return arr;
    };
});
```