# Angular filter with single input and many conditions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L3wra2kL/1/

What I expect is this:
search: 'house paris' -> this line as result: `Sell house in Paris`

I don't really know how to do that: separate words and make them be 'OR conditions' for my filter...

Any Idea?

Comment: Look at this answer. It essentially involves making your own filter
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459798/angularjs-filter-for-multiple-strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your own custom filter. Here is an example of a simple implementation of this integrated with the example you provided

**Filter**

```
app.filter('contains', ['$filter', function(filter) {
    return function (collection, query) {
        var arr = query ? query.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/) : [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
            collection = filter('filter')(collection, arr[i]);
        }
        return collection;
    }
}]);
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zyt9vyzx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can watch on search changes and if there is new value - just split it into words and filter original array by this words.

```
 <div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="search"></p>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in articles">
      {{ x }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Angular code:

```
(function(angular){
     angular.module('app',[])
     .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $filter){
         $scope.articlesOriginal = ['Sell house in Washigton', 'Sell house in Paris', 'Sell car in London', 'Sell car in Washigton'];
         $scope.articles = $scope.articlesOriginal;

       $scope.$watch('search', function(newVal, oldVal){
        if(newVal!==oldVal){
          var filteredList, splitedWords, resultList=$scope.articlesOriginal;

          splitedWords = newVal.trim().split(/\s+/);

          angular.forEach(splitedWords, function(word){
            resultList = $filter('filter')(resultList, word);
          });

          $scope.articles = resultList;

        }
    });
    });
 })(angular);
```

[Updated code on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3wra2kL/1/)